# What is the negation of -z command in Bash?

Tags: bash

I know that '-z' checks whether the variable is empty. But how do you check if the variable is not empty. I tried using '!-z' and '-!z' but it doesn't work. Am I using it correctly?

```
echo "Choose any three player code from above menu. [Case sensitive data]"
    read p1 p2 p3 p4
echo ""
if [ -z "$p4" ]             #run only if the p4 is empty
then
```

I want the if to be such "run is p4 is empty and p3 is not empty.

Comment: Two more notes for understanding: `[` is an alias for `test`. Further, at least for Bash, there is a builtin command named `test`, but there is also an executable named `test` (see `man test`). Running in Bash, you get the builtin by default which is why `help test` gives you usage info for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation operator must be a separate token:

```
if [[ ! -z "${var}" ]] ; then doSomething ; fi
```

However, there's also an "not empty" operator to go along with the "empty" one:

```
if [[ -n "${var}" ]] ; then doSomething ; fi
```

You can find out all about these details by entering `man bash` and searching for `conditional expressions`:

> `-z string` : True if the length of string is zero.
>
> `-n string` : True if the length of string is non-zero.

---

To "run is p4 is empty and p3 is not empty", you can use:

```
if [[ -n "$p3" && -z "$p4" ]] ; then doSomething ; fi
```

If `doSomething` is relatively simple, you can also use the form:

```
[[ -n "$p3" && -z "$p4" ]] && doSomething
```